# Index table with duplicates and match two criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, duplicates, match

What we have is a table that is populated by downloading an invoice from a vendor:

Subscriber------Class-----Deduct
Adams, Tom------A--------$1.00
Adams, Tom------A--------$1.00
Doe, Jane---------A--------$2.00
Smith, Chris------B--------$3.00
Smith, Chris------B--------$3.00
Smith, Chris------B--------$3.00
Jones, Eric-------A--------$4.00
Ives, Kelly--------B--------$5.00
Ives, Kelly--------B--------$5.00

What I'm looking to do is have a separate table for each class (two in this example).  I need a formula that will give me a list of each person in Class A, removing the duplicate entries.  Then the same thing for Class B (same answer as A, so no need posting for Class B).

Subscriber-------Class-------Deduct
Adams, Tom---------A--------$2.00
 
Doe, Jane------------A--------$2.00
Jones, Eric-----------A--------$4.00

Subscriber-------Class-------Deduct
Smith, Chris--------B----------$9.00
 
Ives, Kelly----------B-----------$10.00

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table to quickly group and sum your data.

1. Select your range.
2. Use Insert > Pivot Table, and hit OK.
3. Move 'Class' and 'Subscriber' into the Row area, and 'Deduct' into the values area.
4. Make sure the values are being summed, not counted.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Removed portion related to removing duplicates

Comment: ^ indeed.  I need to add all the deductions for each subscriber and each line represents a different deduction.  Not all subscribers have the same deductions.  So I can't just remove the duplicates, until I have all the deductions for that subscribers tallied.

Comment: I Misunderstood. Ignore the remove duplicates, and proceed straight to the 4 steps relating to pivot table.